# How to select a country from https://www.aliexpress.com/ ship to drowdown menu using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriverwait

On the website https://www.aliexpress.com, I need to change the country from the dropdown menu using selenium

```
<span class="ship-to">
```

I can't find how I click on the country value using selenium

Answer (score 2):

From the *Ship to* [drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu) to select the country as **Afghanistan** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.aliexpress.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'switcher-info')]/span[@class='ship-to']/i"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='address-select-trigger']//span[@class='css_flag css_in']//span[@class='shipping-text']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='address-select-item ']//span[@class='shipping-text' and text()='Afghanistan']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: aliexpress_afghanistan]

Answer (score 0):

you can use ActionChains. Element is your xpath

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
actions.click().perform()
```

You can read more about ActionChains here https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html

or you can use `click()` function
example:

```
country_button = browser.find_element_by_class_name('ship-to')
country_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.List;

public class aliexpress {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver83\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();


        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.aliexpress.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ship-to']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-global']/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/a")).click();

        List <WebElement> lists=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@data-role='content']//li"));
        System.out.println(lists.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
            //System.out.println(LIST.get(i).getText());
            if (lists.get(i).getText().contains("Barbados")) {
                lists.get(i).click();
                break;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want pick "Barbados" you can do above like 

You can do much more in tests  can you try this first and let me know

Comment: 239 country list are here